# Multi-class java applet to jar to html

Tags: java, html, compilation, applet

I have been banging my head against the wall for a few hours, trying to find a 'good' tutorial of how to compile an applet with multiple class files to an html file.

I probably am going about this the wrong way. That or I am mistaken how to do it.

I have 3 classes: Particles(main) ParticleO and Handler

in cmd i am enter the command:

```
jar cvfm Particle.jar manifest.txt *.*
```

manifest:

```
Main-Class: Particles
(anextralinehere)
```

(Im in the src directory)

It compiles just fine (I think, I don’t get any errors)

I make an index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Particle </title>
</head>

<body>
<applet code='Particles.class' 
archive='Particle.jar',
 width="1200", height="600"/>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the file and the applet says it there is an error, and my browser crashes

**edit/update**
the error is:
"ClassNotFoundException" "Particles.class"

Comment: How about you post that error ?

Comment: it doesnt say anything. it just says "error. click for details" in the top left of where the applet should apear on the browser (all browsers). if i click the browser will freeze, sorry if i was unclear

Comment: **edit sorry** error is now apearing in crome :/ ie hates me lol. error was "ClassNotFoundException" "Particles.class"

Comment: Do you have the Particles.class in the same folder as index.html?

Comment: I am curious on what the answer is also.

Comment: Thank you, My problem was i didnt compile the .java to .class before i compiled to jar. **NO** Tutorial that i could find told me this. I assumed that compiling .java to jar compiled it to class aswell. Thank you. (if you want to post it as a answer, ill accept it)

Answer (score 0):

Your "code" attribute is incorrect, what you need to do is code="jarName.className". You DO NOT NEED the .class extension.

In your case, you would need to change your code attribute to code="Particle.Particle"

Hope that helps :)